# GNU Radio "WX GUI Waterfall Sink" Freezes as Timescale is Reduced

Tags: gnuradio

I am trying to capture a 868MHz transmission using an USRPN210 and a RF900 Daughterboard. My GNU Radio flowgraph with all settings is stated below.

[image]

[[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is, when I try to reduce the time scale in the output GUI, the WX waterfall window gets completely stuck (freezes to black). I paste my output below. However, if I not tamper with time scale, the GUI, along with the waterfall and the FFT, continues to run.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WX GUI components in GNU Radio are deprecated. Can you try using QT GUI components instead (the top block GUI option must be changed to match) and report back? If you have similar issues, update your question with the new results.

Both GUIs support zooming in on the spectrum by, if I remember correctly, dragging a box around the area you wish to zoom into. If there is then not enough resolution due to the FFT bin size, you will need to increase the FFT Size, or add a preceding decimating filter block, to get more resolution.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! QT implementation works & dragging around the QT waterfall area zooms in and out! I have set FFT bins to a max of 32768 however, still I don't think the spectrogram is clear enough to see individual chirps. Although I can see packets, my  intension is to observe LoRa chirps clearly. I am also unable to pause the spectrogram. Is there anyway I can pause spectrogram and observe chirps? May I post this as a separate question?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have also updated the question with an image of the problematic low res QT waterfall.

Comment: @Qwertylicious It's not really good to have a question about two topics. Can you maybe post a new question specifically about how to get more time resolution in a waterfall? The new screenshot nicely illustrates that you don't just need a zoom in the GUI.

Comment: Sorry about it. Will keep that in mind. I will post a second question and also edit this question to fit your answer.